# UPDATE subquery nested in SELECT query

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I was wondering what the rules for subqueries exactly are.

For example:

1. can we nest any query statement inside any other statement?

(e.g. an UPDATE query inside an INSERT query... I know it really does not make any sense, ut I was looking at SQL injections and I was wondering if it could work...)

2. Does nesting only works in precise zones of the SQL code? (e.g. after WHERE clause)

I tried a search but didn't found nothing exhaustive on the web.

Comment: Asking "what the rules for subqueries are" is way beyond the scope of SO.  You can start by reading all pages indexed here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/subqueries.html and go from there.  If you can narrow this question down a bit it it will be easier to answer.

Comment: Well I think the two points I wrote are narrow enough...
Can I net an UPDATE subquery inside an INSERT statement?
Does nesting work only if inserted in precise zones of the SQL code?

Comment: I see.  The way it's worded it sounds like the two points are just examples, but that your question is asking something much broader.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't.

What you're talking about wouldn't be sub**queries** (nested SELECTs) but rather sub**mutations** (nested UPDATEs, INSERTs, ...), which I've never heard of.

As for where can you put a subquery - anywhere in your SQL code where a value is expected.